# Change html of specific section of a table?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change specific sell on my table with the bootstrap label.

I did it like this below but it doesnt work

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "<span class="label label-danger">failed</span>";
```

But putting simple html like this works

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "<b>failed</b>";
```

Any idea how to insert that span tag correctly?

Comment: The first one will cause a syntax error, if you open your browser console you will see the error there. If you open a string with double quotes and wish to use double quotes within that string you must backslash them `\"` so your `.innerHTML` should look like this `= "<span class=\"label label-danger\">failed</span>";` same applies if you wrap the string with single quotes, you must backslash the single quotes (if any) within the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the double quotes by single quotes

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "<span class='label label-danger'>failed</span>";
```

Since the double quotes in the class is closing the string